# Menu token module is causing errors

Tags: 7

When creating one of the menu items I accidentally left the "Use tokens in title and in path." option checked while setting the path to .

It is now causing the following error on every page:

Notice: Undefined index: path in menu_token_translated_menu_link_alter() (line 160 of /home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/menu_token/menu_token.module).

I am now trying to delete this menu item and create a new one in its place but I am unable to delte it. It times out. I was able to disable but it is not preventing the error message from displaying. How would I go about deleting this menu item?

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the Menu Token module, then deleting the corrupted link, and re-enabling the module did the trick.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run:

```
variable_set('menu_token_enabled', array());
```

Then that will disable menu_token support for all menu items.

You could then reconfigure those items.

Comment: Thank you. WHere do I run that command?
What if I just disable the module, delete and then reenable it? Would that be the same?

Comment: A bit of a hack, but you could add to template.php or page.tpl.php load a page to run, then remove that line. Personally I would use drush vset